# Combing many csv files with some shared rownames in R?

Tags: csv, merge

I have lots of csv files with lots of compounds and some corresponding columns with data in them. Some of these files have rows with data from the data compounds and some do not. I want to merge these files into one big file with new columns added for each file and a 0 for when there is no data for that compound. Can anyone help?

here is an example of the data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGlwE.png)

I keep getting rowname errors!